GStreamer RTSP server latency problem in c++
First of all, good work everyone. I am creating an RTSP server using the GStreamer C++ API. I am sharing the image I processed with the source OpenCV from my main loop and sending it at 30 FPS. But the image goes to the RTSP client with a delay of about 10 seconds.
A function called need_data is defined. I push frames to the buffer using this function
void VideoStreamer::need_data(GstElement* appsrc, guint /* unused */, gpointer user_data) {
    VideoStreamer* self = static_cast<VideoStreamer*>(user_data);
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(self->queue_mutex);
    if (!self->frame_queue.empty()) {
        cv::Mat frame = self->frame_queue.front();
        self->frame_queue.pop();

        GstBuffer* buffer;
        int size = frame.total() * frame.elemSize();
        buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, size, nullptr);

        GstMapInfo map;
        gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
        memcpy(map.data, frame.data, size);
        gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);

        GstClock* clock = gst_element_get_clock(appsrc);
        GstClockTime pts = self->last_pts + gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 30); // 30 FPS
        self->last_pts = pts;

        GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer) = pts;
        GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 30);

        g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
        gst_buffer_unref(buffer);
    } else {
        g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "end-of-stream", &ret);
    }
}

this is how I create the pipeline
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory,
        "( appsrc name=mysource is-live=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME do-timestamp=true ! "
        "video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! "
        "videoconvert ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=NV12 ! "
        "vaapih264enc rate-control=vbr bitrate=4096 keyframe-period=15 ! "
        "rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");


Did you by accident test a debug build? Also I think you're doing unecessary memory allocations and maybe even the memcpy. Let your videostream at least call gst_buffer_new_allocate when the stream resizes.

I don't quite understand what you are saying. but I have updated this unnecessary call to gst_buffer_new_allocate as you said.

What I mean it that you are allocating the buffer over and over again inside the loop. And you could do that either once (in main) if the resolution does not change or only resize the buffer if resolution does change.

yet my image still updates 10 seconds behind.

Is the callback called 30fps per second? Is it Just 10 Seconds off but stable at 30fps?

yes, 30FPS is stable, but it lags behind.

Does it make a diffrence set the keyframe interval to 1 ?
